# How to change android AppCompatButton's text color on pressed

Tags: android, button, styles

I have created following style for custom AppCompatButton.

```
<style name="AppTheme.secondary_button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/secondary_button_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/menu_blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/secondary_button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
</style>
```

What is the attribute to change text color on button pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you just need to replace the textColor you specified with a selector:

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/grey" /> <!-- (for accessibility) -->
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

and then assign it like this:
android:textColor="@drawable/button_foreground_selector"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    style="@style/CustomAppCompatButtonStyle"
    android:text="Hi, Neo"/>
```

Not clicked button:

[image: Not clicked]

Clicked button:

[image: Clicked]

Style I used:

```
<style name="CustomAppCompatButtonStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_foreground_selector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution didn't work...:(

Comment: @Neo I just created a dummy project with AppCompat.Button with custom style and solution I proposed. It works fine for me. I've uploaded it to DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1wamgtd06b20ne/NeoTestApp.zip?dl=0, can you give it a try?

Comment: Also added screenshots and extended description to my answer above.

Comment: @ Konstantin Thanks a lot!!! Your project is working as intended. But somehow with same implementation it doesn't work in my project. I am looking into what exactly I am missing.

Comment: @ Konstantin I am applying extra android:textColor="@color/gray" after style attribute, silly mistake....:(